# Rails SSL messed up content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx, capistrano

I just finished installing an SSL certificate on my Rails app using Rubber & Capistrano to deploy.  Now, my app isn't showing any of the styling, the images are huge, javascript isn't working anymore either.

This app was previously deployed in AWS and was only available using HTTP, so I made my changes to the Rubber deploy config files and ran `cap deploy`, now this is the result.

Here's what It should look like:
[image: The right styling]

And this is what it looks like with SSL on:
[image: No styling anymore]

Here are the files that I modified:

**rubber/role/nginx/unicorn_nginx.conf**

```html
<%
  @path = "/etc/nginx/rubber/unicorn_nginx.conf"
%>


upstream unicorn_server {
 # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
 server unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock
 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  <% if Rubber.env == 'production' %>
  # SSL
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mycert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;
  <% end %>

  <% if Rubber.env == 'staging' %>
  # SSL Cap
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mycert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
  <% end %>

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  server_name <%= [ rubber_env.domain, rubber_env.web_aliases ].flatten.compact.join(" ") %>;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

  # Location of our static files
  root <%= Rubber.root + "/public" %>;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    <% if Rubber.env == 'production' || Rubber.env == 'staging' %>
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    <% end %>
    proxy_redirect off;

    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
      break;
    }
  }

 # this rewrites all the requests to the maintenance.html
 # page if it exists in the doc root. This is for capistrano's
 # disable web task
 if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html)
 {
   rewrite  ^(.*)$  /system/maintenance.html last;
   break;
 }

 error_page   500 502 503 504  /500.html;
 location = /500.html
 {
   root <%= Rubber.root + "/public" %>;
 }
 error_page 404  /404.html;
 location = /404.html
 {
   root <%= Rubber.root + "/public" %>;
 }
}
```

**config/environments/staging.rb**

```html
Rails.application.configure do
  config.host = "dev.server.com"
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: config.host }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { host: config.host }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    user_name: 'xxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxx',
    domain: config.host,
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 587,
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.force_ssl = true

  config.log_level = :info

  config.asset_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
  config.action_controller.asset_host = config.asset_host
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = config.asset_host

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? Normally this would be caused that your assets are referenced with no-ssl url which creates a security gap.

Comment: Or styles etc. are loaded by non-ssl. Many browsers warns in console and doesn't load?

Comment: I've seen this happen with cdn's - you may be able to switch this over to https `config.asset_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"`

Comment: Swards, you're right... want to put that in as the answer and I'll mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDNs will often allow either protocol.  And https will work if you are in the http protocol, in case that comes up in development or in a staging server.

The opposite will not work.

Switch this over to use 'https'

```
config.asset_host = "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```